# Using macro results vs macro expansion in PGFplotstable

Tags: macros, pgfplotstable, expansion

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\rightOutput}{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{rawcutoffs.csv}\rawdata

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        columns/LetterGrade/.style={string type,column type = l},
        columns/Average/.style={column type = r},
    ]{\rawdata}
}

\def\paramOutput#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{rawcutoffs.csv}\rawdata

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    #1
    ]{\rawdata}
}

\newcommand*{\parser}[1]{%
    \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{n}{\x}}{columns/\y/.style={column type = r},}{columns/\y/.style={string type,column type = l},}%
    }%
}

\def\straighttext{%
    columns/LetterGrade/.style={string type,column type = l},
    columns/Average/.style={column type = r},
}

\begin{document}
%This macro is ultimately what I desire, and it works
\rightOutput

%This macro works, but it is not what I desire
\expandafter\paramOutput\expandafter{\straighttext}

%This macro doesn't work at all - WHY?
%\expandafter\paramOutput\expandafter{\parser{s/LetterGrade,n/Average}}
\end{document}
```

The CSV file rawcutoffs.csv looks like:

```
LetterGrade,Average
A,90
B,80
C,70
```

When I attempt to use the command parser, it doesn't feed the results of parser into the paramOutput command - instead, it feeds the code itself into paramOutput. **I was curious if there is a way to get the results of the command parser to be used as the argument of paramOutput?** When I use the command straighttext, it gives me the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output to `\parser` needs to be expanded before you give it to `\pgfplotstabletypeset`. To get around this I think that the easiest way is to build a string, called `\specs` below, that contains the "output" of `\parser`, which you then force to expand using something like

```
 \xdef\myplot{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\specs]}
```

Below I have built `\specs` using `\xappto` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) -- it is used to append stuff to `\specs`. I have also moved the `\parser` code inside `\paramOutput` and made `\paramOutput` accept a comma separated list of specifications. It doesn't need to be done this way but it seem more natural to me since `\paramOutput` now builds `\specs`. I have also used `\ifx` for the string comparison (of `\x` to `n` or `s`), which requires an extra `\expandafter` to force `\x` to expand (for some reason I tend to avoid `\ifthenelse`...).

With these changes your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\rightOutput}{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{rawcutoffs.csv}\rawdata%
    %
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
        columns/LetterGrade/.style={string type,column type = l},
        columns/Average/.style={column type = r},
    ]{\rawdata}
}

\def\paramOutput#1{%
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{rawcutoffs.csv}\rawdata%
    \def\specs{}%
    \foreach \x/\y in {#1} {
      \expandafter\ifx\x n\xappto\specs{columns/\y/.style={column type = r},}%
      \else\xappto\specs{columns/\y/.style={string type,column type = l},}%
      \fi
    }%
    \xdef\myplot{\noexpand\pgfplotstabletypeset[\specs]}%
    \myplot{\rawdata}%
}

\begin{document}
    %This macro is ultimately what I desire, and it works
    \rightOutput

    %This macro now works!
    \paramOutput{s/LetterGrade,n/Average}
\end{document}
```

This gives what I think is the desired output:

[image]